# Implement paging for certain type for rows

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to implement pagination only for certain type of users. The table structure is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 3)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String login;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 64)
    private String salt;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String type;
    .....
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

}
```

Query:

```
@Override
public Page<Users> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
}
```

How I can limit the query only to select `type` admin, super_admin and etc.

I suppose that I need to add limitation like IN (`admin`, `super_admin`)?

Comment: create two methods, two separate actions

Comment: @YCF_L can you show me code example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the easiest way is to use the naming convention and use  `findAllByTypeIn`:

```
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
  Page<User> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page,String... types));
}
```

but if you have more complex search criteria I would consider using specifications

*Spring Data JPA* supports specifications, you can extend your repository interface with the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface, as follows:

```
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```

Write your specification

```
class UserSpecs {

    public static Specification<User> isOfType(String type) {

        return new Specification<User>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                return builder.equal(root.get("type"), type);
            }
        };
    }


    public static Specification<User> isInTypes(String... types) {

        return new Specification<User>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
               In<String> inClause = builder.in(root.get("type"));
               for (String type: types) {
                 inClause.value(type);      
               }
               return inClause;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and get the result via

```
dao.findAll(UserSpecs.isOfType("admin").or(UserSpecs.isOfType("super_admin")) ,PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

or if you prefer to use *in*

```
dao.findAll(UserSpecs.isInTypes("admin","super_admin")) ,PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there more easy way like using annotations with SQL query?

Comment: `String... types`? maybe I need to send it as array?

Comment: sure or use a collection if you prefer. If you use ```String... types``` you can send a single string without needing it to convert to a collection or an array...

Comment: @PeterPenzov if the answer help you don't forgot to accept and up-vote the answer